# Creating a Basic Timeline in Latex

Tags: latex, timeline

I am trying to construct a simple timeline in LaTeX with dates below points on the line and words above the line referring to a range.

I have included an image of what I am looking for that I constructed in Powerpoint. When adding this as an image into latex, the scaling makes the image unclear. Figured it will also be more professional to include actual latex timeline.

[image: Timeline for LaTeX]